Exercise question on work done by friction

In the solution to this question the displacement was not taken instead the distance along the curve was taken which has left me confused.

You will probably want to think about energy for this problem. So how much kinetic energy is converted to heat by friction? Friction acts all along the curve as the block slides. At every point, friction acts in the direction opposite the motion. At every short interval you can calculate the work done by friction $W=F\cdot d$. You might think about how to add up the work done over all those short segments.
